# Push Notification not receiving in sleep mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I am working on Silent Push notification to receive notifications in sleep mode of the device (after 5 mins of device's lock ) 
I referred [this](http://www.g8production.com/post/72656082173/ios7-multitasking-silent-notifications) link . But i am not able to get notification on deep sleep Mode.Help me to fix this!

Comment: how r u sending push notification? APNS or FCM?

Comment: I am using APNS @Waseem Khan